# If a buggy application underperforms, it it possible server tuning could have no affect?

Tags: linux, mysql, performance, tomcat, tuning

To set the stage, imagine if you will:

A read-heavy Tomcat Application with MySQL on Red Hat Enterprise Linux with some problematic Java Class files which resulted in the application performing a lot of time-wasting operations and causing the application to perform very slowly. The server, a blade server with 10K SAS disk, 32GB RAM and 8 core xeon @ 3 GHZ.  I tried tuning MySQL and Tomcat, but the page loads got no faster no matter what types of optimizations were made.

**My question is:** if the bottleneck of an application is caused by the code itself, is it possible, and in what circumstances, would it render and type of server configuration useless?  My loose theory is that, if you have headroom in terms of resources, and the application itself is simply slow due to inefficiencies such as useless recursions, useless DB reads, etc.. then you are at that point limited by your transfer rate, clock speed, disk read speeds, etc.. things that tuning will not help, only new, faster hardware would address at that point.

Is that accurate?  Could someone elaborate on this?

Comment: In my experience with Java on Tomcat/JBoss/Jetty tuning at that end can have no impact on performance if the issue lies with the underlying OS with respect to bounding issues where I/O for resources such as HDD's, network, or CPUs are the limited resource.

Comment: via @NoTime - If you hit a bottleneck with the application, due to an error, it will not matter how fast the machine running this error is. Almost like if you are stuck running in circles, it does not matter how fast you run in a circle, you still will not get out. (If there is proper error checking though, you may hit a set limit faster, and reach an exit error faster).

Comment: I am not talking about errors per se, I am just talking about things like, the application opening a new DB connection for every select statement, instead of making proper use of the DB pool or using a single connection for multiple queries.